# Wordpress can't upload files

Tags: permissions, apache2, mysql, lamp, wordpress

I have installed LAMP stack and Wordpress on a local apache2 server using the tutorials here-

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu
2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04

But when I try to upload a media file (image/sound) I get the error-

```
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2015/01.
```

What might be wrong? I have added my user to www-data group and **chown**'d the directory **/var/www/**  as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use this script to fix wordpress permission:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This script configures WordPress file permissions based on recommendations
# from http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_permissions
#
# Author: Michael Conigliaro <mike [at] conigliaro [dot] org>
#
WP_OWNER=www-data # <-- wordpress owner
WP_GROUP=www-data # <-- wordpress group
WP_ROOT=$1 # <-- wordpress root directory
WS_GROUP=www-data # <-- webserver group

# reset to safe defaults
find ${WP_ROOT} -exec chown ${WP_OWNER}:${WP_GROUP} {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT} -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT} -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

# allow wordpress to manage wp-config.php (but prevent world access)
chgrp ${WS_GROUP} ${WP_ROOT}/wp-config.php
chmod 660 ${WP_ROOT}/wp-config.php

# allow wordpress to manage wp-content
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -exec chgrp ${WS_GROUP} {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find ${WP_ROOT}/wp-content -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

save it to a file and run it and pass it your wp installation directory:

```
wget https://gist.github.com/Adirael/3383404/raw/6c5446d56477426faeb709e5b807f00422acdea2/fix-wordpress-permissions.sh
chmod +x fix-wordpress-permissions.sh
sudo ./fix-wordpress-permissions.sh /var/www/html
```

https://gist.github.com/Adirael/3383404

Comment: This did the trick (as is often the issue, files were owned by a user that copied them, rather than www-data). Thanks for providing this helpful script.

Comment: At the risk of adding a "me too" comment, I'd like to say that I exhausted numerous search results on the topic from StackOverflow and elsewhere, and *this* is the set of commands that actually worked for my situation (like OP, I just wanted a WordPress site to be owned by a non-privileged user, but was receiving issue when trying to upload). This answer should be first in Google searches. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the link to the recommended permissions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress#File_Permissions

Comment: this made my site 403 forbidden omg ://////

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this helps solve your problem and explain whats going on, to help you in the future too.
When you go into the wordpress "dashboard" and upload files - the "user" that is performing the changes to the filesystem is`www-data` (i.e. libapache2-mod-php5 via apache webserver).
Therefore in order to make changes in `wp-content/uploads/2015/01.`, `www-data` needs to **either** have write permissions to the directory or **own** the directory.
This means you can either give the folder liberal permissions by running:

```
chmod -R 777 wp-content/uploads
```

Note: you will have to `cd` into the  wordpress directory first, and if you dont currently own the folder, you will need to  use `sudo`

However in my experience, this will result in problems , i.e. once you fix that permission issue, you will likely run into more problems when wordpress tries to write  files to other directories e.g. when it updates, new plugins etc. so in that case i would use:

```
sudo chown -R www-data <wordpress-parent-directory>
```

and let `www-data` own the entire folder.

Note: its not such a big deal on local install but when you move to production server, need to be careful with permissions, and generally only give webserver absolute **minimum** permissions it needs to do its job.

Comment: @goelakash I sure hope you did not do this `chmod -R 777 wp-content/uploads`.  The answer from sajjadG is what you should follow.

Comment: I agreed with @Rinzwind do not give 777 permission to uploads directory, It means anyone ( including your visitor) can upload files in this directory. it will make your application vulnerable, instead follow sajjadG 's instructions, I would like you to consider reading this article http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/08/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/

Answer (score 0):

Is the wp-content directory really where you think it is?

I notice that the article in question created a directory in `/var/www/html/` but wordpress will  thing it will be under the wordpress directory that you extracted from the compressed tarfile. In my case it was `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content` which was a softlink to another directory. Once I had fixed the privs and ownership in this location it worked for me.